# Handling dependencies in a Python micro service environment

Tags: python, dependencies, microservices

Background: I want to make plenty of micro services written in Python (Django, Flask... does not matter for now) for intranet use. Let's say there's going to be an auth service, a notification service (email and/or internet communicators integration) and some kind of data resource service. 
So a users goes though auth (e.g. get's a JWT) then hit's the data service to change something. That change should trigger a call to the notification service to send the notification.
The questions begin from how to handle and should I even consider doing a kind of clients for my services? 
What I have in mind right now is to make Python packages or simply use git sub modules to handle that, like so:
Having and endpoint `data.service.local/api/v1/food` I would like (I think) to make a 'provider' that would allow me to use that endpoint in a easy way:

```
class DataServiceProvider(object):

    BASE_URL = settings.DATA_SERVICE_URL

    def create_food(self, name):
        return requests.post(BASE_URL + 'food', {'name': name})
```

Should I even bother? I aim for having dozens of my other services hitting this one (especially the notification one) so I guess I should. But where to store those providers? Outside in another repository named `{service_name}-client` and use the package in any other service that needs to use it?

Appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some trial and failure I settled on using both git sub modules and python packages. The directory tree looks like this:

```
main (repo)
├── auth (repo)
│   ├── auth-cleint (repo)
│   │   └── setup.py
│   └── requirements (contains an editable entry to ./auth-client)
├── notify (repo)
│   ├── notify-client (repo)
│   │   └── setup.py
│   └── requirements (-e ./notify-client and git+auth-client)
├── docker-compose.yml
└── data (repo)
    └── requirements (git+notify-client and git+auth-client)
```

The auth, notify, data are separate git repositories linked as sub modules under the main repo. Same goes for clients inside their service Django projects. I install the clients within their services in editable mode just to make my development easy. Once I'll go staging/prod I'll use git+ links.

This works for now in here https://github.com/PyPila/amok (not a commercial project - used to learn) if someone's interested to dive deeper.

One hint in this moment of time I have to use a deprecated `--process-dependency-links` flag when using `pip` as my client packages depend on some other private packages. `pip` maintainers set that flag as deprecated but it will stay there until they figure out how to solve those 'deep dependencies'.